# Scraping Google results

Tags: c#, web-scraping

How would I do that in C#? When I get the source of "[`http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=foobar`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=foobar)", I get a script. I thought about using the AJAX API to get the results in JSON format, but it goes only to the first 32 results.

Comment: Scraping Google is against [TOS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS).

Comment: Yeah, Google has an [API for that](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).

Comment: Use their API http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html, or don't do it at all.

Comment: if you need past top 32 results, you are (probably) doing it wrong.

Comment: Maybe this is someone from Microsoft... Just make sure you don't save any search results with the word 'torsoraphy' in them.

Comment: @RQDQ: Yeah, because that would be a horrible misspelling and probably wouldn't have what you were looking for anyway.

Comment: Check out http://scraping.compunect.com
That's an open source PHP scraping script.
While C# can not be called compatible to PHP, it's not difficult to translate between both languages.
libCurl is available for both.

Comment: According to this guide on [Scraping Google With Python](https://blog.goog.io/web/scraping/2019/12/30/how-to-scrape-google-with-python.html) you can specify the max number of results to return with the `num` parameter. The max is `num=100`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to scrape a Javascript based website like Google in C# and without relying on any API I recommend the following alternatives:

1. Update to IE 9 and use the WebBrowser control in your Windows Forms application. Automate the WebBrowser control to retrieve information from the site.
2. If you want a headless browser, use HtmlUnit under .NET. This is more complex but you can see this article: [Using HtmlUnit on .NET for Headless Browser Automation](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/)

Sadly, the Google API will be closed soon following their deprecation rules. I have written an article about it at: [Google Search NoAPI](http://blog.databigbang.com/google-search-no-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Google's AJAX API is pretty useless for most use cases.

You can create a script to search and scrape the top 100 results. To avoid being blocked you can request slowly or use multiple proxies. Make sure you set your user-agent to something not suspicious.

Answer (score -1):

I think Google will block you if you try it on a larger scale.
If you want to get blocked and break the TOS, you could use Watin to control a browser to overcome javascripts.

If you could describe why you need more results, maybe we can suggest a method that doesn't break the TOS.